# AVPlayer is paused after starting to play audio live stream

Tags: ios, avplayer

When I try to play the live stream the player is paused.

This is how I create the player:

```
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.url];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];

    self.audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];

    if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)){
        self.audioPlayer.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = NO;
    }
```

then play:

```
 if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)){
            [self.audioPlayer playImmediatelyAtRate:1.0];
        } else {
            [self.audioPlayer play];
        }
```

When I do KVO with `timeControlStatus` and `status`
I see this in logs:

```
PLAYER: AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay

PLAYER: AVPlayerTimeControlStatusWaitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate

<AVPlayerItem: 0x2812c88c0, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x2810f6e40, URL = https://*****128.mp3>>

PLAYER: AVPlayerWaitingWithNoItemToPlayReason

PLAYER: AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPause
```

Comment: Check the player state . (May be problm with your video , or internet)